# YouTube embed code Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I am trying to embed a video on our website.  The YouTube HTML5 embed code naturally works just fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari but in IE11 it's just a black box.

Here's the embed code that doesn't work in IE11

```
 <iframe width="900" height="506" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NWCep6fo2y0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However if I swap out "embed" for "v" it works, although looks uglier.

```
 <iframe width="900" height="506" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/NWCep6fo2y0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is not unique to my PC here at the office, I've tried it on a number of workstations with the same result.

Both videos are embedded here:

http://www.ansac.com/products

Any idea as to why this is happening other than ugh, Internet Explorer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with IE settings:

1. From Internet Explorer, select the Tools menu, then the Options...
2. In the Internet Options dialog, select the Advanced tab...
3. Scroll down until you see the Security options.  Enable the checkbox "Allow
   active content to run in files on My Computer".

Or

Turn off compability view in IE

Comment: Well that's annoying.  If it's turned on by default I have to assume that most IE11 visitors to our site will have this issue.  No other work arounds other than changing the embed code to that fall back?

Comment: Perhaps turning off compability view in IE (Edited my answer accordingly)

Comment: Yeah, that's much better.  Didn't even know I had our site added as such.  Thanks again

Comment: This is a solution from the point of view of one user. But I need that our website works for all users, I can not instruct 10 000 customers to change their IE settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this has solved my problem: https://polyfill.io/

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how this solves the issue at hand?

Comment: It's been a while ago but I _think_ I have just included the script tag in the HTML `head` like that: `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>`.